# How to make full screen html background video for half page?

Tags: html, css

How to make html background video for half page?

```css
.video {
    position: fixed; no-repeat;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index:-1000;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I use this code for full background video but I want only for the header section.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the height value to 50% and delete the top:50% :

```
{
position: fixed; no-repeat;
left: 50%;
z-index:-1000;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: the video is appearing in header and  end of the section. 
Any idea about how to remove the video from the section area ?

Comment: Please add some markup code or maybe a fiddle/plnkr ?

Comment: It worked height value 50% and position: absolute. Thank you.